# Add unlimited values into objects from textbox in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Can you please show me a simple code which add unlimited values into JavaScript objects. I don't want single view "Toyota, 2014". I want show lists value after I add value from textbox.

```
 class Car {
      constructor(name, year) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
      }
    }
```

At code below, this is single value to add, but I need add many value doesn't matter, how many of number I want to add.

```
const myCar = new Car("Toyota", 2014); 

I expect to view many different values like

Toyota, 2014
Opel, 2018
Volkswagen, 2021
and many mores
```

Comment: Try with [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an array of `Car` objects:

```
const cars = [];
```

Then adding a `Car` is:

```
cars.push(new Car(make, year));
// Or some people do, which also works:
cars[cars.length] = new Car(make, year);
```

...where `make` and `year` come from the text boxes.

When you want to list them all, you'll use some kind of loop (the exact kinds depends on how you're listing them). My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) shows the various ways you can loop through arrays.

More about arrays [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).